# I am unable to retrieve the firebase database to the navigation bar in the main activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gallery

I am creating a Blog app, but when I move on from the Setup account activity to the mainactivity the app gets force closed if I am registering as a normal user, but this is not the nature if I sign in with Google account ! below are my setup account and mainactivity java files.

```
**Here is my setup activity**

                            mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();
                            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                            mStorageImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images");
                            mDatabseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);
                            mSetupImageBtn = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.setupImageBtn);
                            mNameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setupNameField);
                            mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setupSubmitBtn);
                            mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

                //CLiking on submit button
                            mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    startSetupAccount();
                                }
                            });
        //TO setup image in the circular image view and firing the gallrey intent
                            mSetupImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                                    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);

                                }
                            });

                        }



               //Getting the firebase databse to setup the account 
                    private void startSetupAccount() {
                        final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
                        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&& mImageUri != null)
                        mProgress.setMessage("Finishing setup...");
                        mProgress.show();
                        {

                            StorageReference filepath = mStorageImage.child((mImageUri.getLastPathSegment()));
                            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    String downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                    mDatabseUsers.child(user_id).child("name").setValue(name);
                                    mDatabseUsers.child(user_id).child("image").setValue(downloadUri);

                                    mProgress.dismiss();
                                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                   mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            });


                        }
                    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
  {

      Uri imageUri = data.getData();
      CropImage.activity(imageUri)
              .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
              .setAspectRatio(1,1)
              .start(this);
  }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mImageUri= result.getUri();
                mSetupImageBtn.setImageURI(mImageUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
    }
               ## Main activity ##
```

This is my main activity and i want that my navigation drawer is able to retrieve the data I stored from the setup activity that is the name and the image to be setup n the string text and the image view of the navigation drawer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private RecyclerView mBlogList;

//       <!--Initializing firebase variables-->
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabseUsers;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "Coverphoto";
    private Context context;
    private boolean mProcessLike = false;

//       <!--Initalizing Drawable variables-->
    private NavigationView mNavigationView;
    private TextView mName;
    private String name;
    private String image;
    private Uri photoUrl;
    private ImageView mPic;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// <!--Collasping toolbar fetch Id's and display menu_items-->
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_menu);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Heapooh");
//       <!--Firebase Authenticationat-- >
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            }
        };

//       <!--Putting variables to the databse and keeping them synced -- >
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://heapooh-9d5e2.firebaseio.com/").child("Blog");
        mDatabseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
        mDatabseUsers.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

//       <!--Setting up the recyclerView-- >
        mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mBlogList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

//       <!--Method to check if the user already exist defined below -- >
        checkUserExist();
//       <!--Adding the toggle to drawable -- >
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mName = (TextView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mPic = (ImageView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.setupImage);

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                getCurrentinfo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void getCurrentinfo() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            for (UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
                // Id of the provider (ex: google.com)
                String providerId = profile.getProviderId();

                // UID specific to the provider
                String uid = profile.getUid();

                // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
                name = profile.getDisplayName();
                photoUrl = profile.getPhotoUrl();
                mName.setText(name);

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(photoUrl.toString())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_send)
                        .resize(120, 120)
                        .transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(mPic);


            }
            ;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
//                            <!--On start method after authentication populated the Cardviews in the recycler views-->

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.blog_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        )


        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
                final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();
//                           <!--Hold 's the title,description,username,uid,key for the cardviews-->
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
                viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                viewHolder.setmLikebtn(post_key);

                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
//                                 <!--Once the key is fetched it takes u to the blogsingle activity to read the full description over here -- >
                        Intent singleBlogIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BlogSingleActivity.class);
                        singleBlogIntent.putExtra("blog_id", post_key);
                        startActivity(singleBlogIntent);

                    }
                });
//                            <!--To add or remove the liked value database once the like button is pressed and vice versa -- >
                        viewHolder.mLikebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                mProcessLike = true;
                                {
                                    mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if (mProcessLike) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                                                    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                                    mProcessLike = false;
                                                } else {
                                                    mDatabaseLike.child(post_key).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue("RandomValue");
                                                    mProcessLike = false;

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }

                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        };
        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
//                   <!--Method to check if user exist is called over here-->

    private void checkUserExist() {
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            mDatabseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                    if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {

                        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                        setupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(setupIntent);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
//                            <!--Retriving key to post to new page -->

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        ImageButton mLikebtn;
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseLike;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            mLikebtn = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.like_btn);
            mDatabaseLike = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mDatabaseLike.keepSynced(true);
        }

        public void setmLikebtn(final String post_key) {
            mDatabaseLike.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
//                                <!--Like button adds to database and disliking it removes from database -- >
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        mLikebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);


                    } else {
                        mLikebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

//               <!--Fetching thetitle,desc, username andto set them>

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
//            TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
//            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {

            TextView post_username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_username);
            post_username.setText(username);

        }

//               <!--Use picassolibrary to load images-->

        public void setImage(final Context context, final String image) {
            final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_Image);
            Picasso.with(context).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(image).into(post_image);
                }
            });
        }

    }

//    <!-- Drawer and menu items-->


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout) {
            logout();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_videos) {
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_bookmarks) {
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void logout() {

        mAuth.signOut();

    }
```

Comment: if it is crashing then what is written in the logcat?

Comment: It gives error in the getcurrentinfo section and the picasso section ..but while i use google login it works fine and upload my google profile pic to the navigation drawer in the Mainactivity.